# Ansible module for adding an SELinux context equivalence

Tags: ansible, selinux

Is there an Ansible module that allows an SELinux context equivalence to be added? The command is:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /home/xxx /srv/xxx
```

This makes SELinux treat `/srv/xxx` as equivalent to `/home/xxx`.

While I could use the `command` module, it only works once; after that it always fails with:

```
ValueError: Equivalence class for /srv/xxx already exists
```

I could use the `shell` module and run a command like:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /home/xxx /srv/xxx || true
```

but since the command runs every time, Ansible always reports something has changed (even if the context equivalence already existed).

Comment: As temporary workaround you can use changed_when to avoid changed status in the shell module

Answer (score 2):

Closest Ansible module to `semanage fcontext` is [community.general.sefcontext](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/sefcontext_module.html). Looks like it is idempotent and supports diff mode.

However, no equilviant to `--equal` that I can find. Write the context you want as the `setype` parameter. For example, `user_home_t`. I would prefer the source of truth be the playbook in this case, not some other file on the host.

Should you want `--equal`, consider writing it yourself and submitting an enhancement pull request for the module.